# Ctrl + t - open new Tab doesn't work in Selenium + Firefox Python

Tags: python-3.x, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Are there is any function abolished by Selenium ?

**Goal :**
open new tab like "Ctrl + t"

**Environment:**

- Window 7
- Firefox 68
- Python 3.7

**No Reaction of both script below :**

```
# 1 
dr.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
# 2 
ActionChains(dr).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Some tutorial video 3~4yrs ago showing the scripts below worked but not in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a new tab in the following ways :

- **SendKey method**

  Mac OS

  `dr.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')`

  Other OS

  `dr.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')`
- **Action method**

  `ActionChains(dr).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()`
- **ExecuteScript method**

  `dr.execute_script("window.open('','_blank');")`

  Or with specific url

  `dr.execute_script("window.open('URL');")`

**--UPDATE--**

If your issue is to want to switch to a particular tab, then do this :

Before do your actions, handles your current tab with :

```
first_tab = dr.window_handles[0]
```

Then do your actions which will bring to a new tab. May `.click` action.

Add some sleep for wait load new tab `dr.implicitly_wait(....)`.

Handle new tab window with :

```
second_tab = dr.window_handles[1]
```

Now you can swith to you want tab :

```
dr.switch_to.window(first_tab / second_tab)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: with windows dr.execute_script("window.open('URL');") worked.

Comment: but it isn't in the same window. i need only "open new tab" because i need to check the downloading progress refer to the current task which the window is doing . fp.set_preference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart", True)
fp.set_preference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1", True)
fp.set_preference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2", True) or all False as well . still no reaction .

Comment: Kandan Siva  ActionChains(dr).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform() or dr.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')

 worked for you ? (open tab in same window, not in new window )

Comment: @rane the current task bring you to a new tab ? and you want to go to the tab ? if it's true, you just swith it. i've updated code, please try.

Comment: Than you Frian , i am stucking at "open new tab" after start browse as google.com , let alone switch tab. If the current code its works for your PC , i have to try on another PC to get closer to the real problem.

Comment: Frain , thank you , dr.execute_script("window.open('URL');")  works after dr.get("URL") i found the gd example in github.[link]( https://gist.github.com/lrhache/7686903) ; btw , dr.execute_script("window.open('about:downloads');") will get error .

Answer (score 3):

The question is the new gecko driver (marionette), has two contexts:

1) Chrome (The browser itself)

2) Content (The webpage content)

You need to tell selenium in which context do you want to send the action.

For me (Python 3.6, Selenium 3.141, gecko driver 0.26.0, firefox 75)  this code works:

```
driver.execute("SET_CONTEXT", {"context": "chrome"})
    urlbar=driver.find_element('id','urlbar')
    urlbar.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "t")
driver.execute("SET_CONTEXT", {"context": "content"})
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all 3 methods.

Nothing happens: no new tab.

I trust the window.open method, because it works if I use _self instead of _blank.
Somehow, Selenium seems to block any method that opens a new tab.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33488482)